# Are there universal interjections?

Tags: interjections

I was watching a japanese videos about the use of a, aa etc. to express surprise, disappointment, understanding, etc. which are pretty much the same than the ah, ahh of Spanish, a completely unrelated language (h mute so they sound practically the same).

My question is, is there any interjection that is used in all known languages or that is used in so many that's considered universal?

Comment: /a/ is a sound that can come from a wide open mouth shouting. Lots of other sounds can't.

Comment: @jlawler Yes. And people falling off cliffs never shout /u/!